# PostgreSQL - Count and Case combined

Tags: postgresql, case, aggregate-functions

I have the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT sk.kontonummer as Sachkonto, 
CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 2 ktr.kostentraeger_nr + ' 
 and more' 
ELSE ktr.kostentraeger_nr END,
 (...)
```

As a result, I can get 2 or more rows. 
When I get 3 or more rows I want to write in behind right after `"ktr.kostentraeger_nr"` 'and more' (as a String), if not then only the result itself.

The query itself is not executable because of the count function - the bold text is just the idea how I think it SHOULD work. 
Is there any way to fulfill my request?

To clarify my requirements an example: 
[image]

Thank you so much, I already wasted a whole day because of this problem...

Comment: please read this and update your question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056. Please don't put pictures of the data structure.

Comment: Sorry for the bad question structure, I will update the data structure tomorrow -  I promise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to use `OVER()`. Don't know your query or your database structure, but here's a simple example that should help.

Let's have a table **test** like

```
id | integer_value | text_value
---+---------------+------------
1  | 5             | a
2  | 7             | b
3  | 8             | c
4  | 1             | d
```

To have the `COUNT` of the actual query, we use the window function `OVER()`.

```
SELECT id,integer_value
    CASE
-- since you have to add text, the integer must be cast as text.
        WHEN COUNT(*) OVER () > 2 THEN integer_value::text||' and more'
        ELSE integer_value::text
    END AS altered_integer,
    text_value
-- To test you can change the condition. When lower than 3, it shows just the value,
-- if you change the query and set lower than 4, the column will have 'and more'.
FROM instituciones WHERE id<3
--FROM instituciones WHERE id<4
```

The query results When id < 3:

```
id | integer_value | altered_integer | text_value
---+---------------+-----------------+------------
1  | 5             | 5               | a
2  | 7             | 7               | b
```

The query results When id < 4:

```
id | integer_value | altered_integer | text_value
---+---------------+-----------------+------------
1  | 5             | 5 and more      | a
2  | 7             | 7 and more      | b
3  | 8             | 8 and more      | c
```

When using `OVER()`, you say to the `COUNT` function that it has to count over the whole query rows.

**NOTE:** If the query doesn't have any condition, `OVER()` will return the count of the whole table

Comment: Thank you! Fixed my problem.